# error in C# datagridview filter specific content

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview

i'm trying to show secific dates record when i select that date. i have filled my datagridview like this:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Fakhar Zaman\\documents\\visual studio2010\\Projects\\LabManagement\\LabManagement\\Management.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, expenseTitle, expenseAmount, date, paidBy, expenseType from Expense", con);
DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds, "Expense");
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, date, itemName, quantity, itemSold, priceBuy, soldPrice, totalSold, profit from ItemRecord", con);
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds, "ItemRecord");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

This code is working fine and showing the values in datagridview. But when i want to filter content for specific date, it doesnt do that, instead it shows the complete record again.
Filtering code is below:

```
string plus = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord", con);
var dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
//MessageBox.Show(plus +" , " + date);
this.itemRecordBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("date >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND date < '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", date, plus);
//string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
```

Please suggest me some solution.

> > > Whenever I fill the dataset using the auto-generated code, it works fine and filters the specific content, but i need the above code to
> > >       work fine
>
> ```
>         this.expenseTableAdapter.Fill(this.managementDataSet21.Expense);
>
>         this.itemRecordTableAdapter.Fill(this.managementDataSet21.ItemRecord);*/
> ```

Here is the complete code of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LabManagement
{
    public partial class calculation : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con;



        public calculation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void calculation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Fakhar Zaman\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\LabManagement\\LabManagement\\Management.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, expenseTitle, expenseAmount, date, paidBy, expenseType from Expense", con);
            DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Expense");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, date, itemName, quantity, itemSold, priceBuy, soldPrice, totalSold, profit from ItemRecord", con);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "ItemRecord");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            /*
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'managementDataSet21.Expense' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.expenseTableAdapter.Fill(this.managementDataSet21.Expense);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'managementDataSet21.ItemRecord' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.itemRecordTableAdapter.Fill(this.managementDataSet21.ItemRecord);*/
            dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           // this.itemRecordBindingSource.Filter = "date = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "'"; 

            string plus = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord Where date >='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND date < '" + date + "'", con);
            //adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord", con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

            var dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            //MessageBox.Show(plus +" , " + date);
           //this.itemRecordBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("date >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND date < '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", date, plus);
            /*string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
            */


            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
            }
            label2.Text = sum.ToString();




            ///// for expense table:

            SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            myadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Expense Where date >='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND date < '" + date + "'", con);
            //myadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Expense", con);
            var expensedataset = new DataSet();
            myadapter.Fill(expensedataset);
            //MessageBox.Show(plus +" , " + date);
            //this.expenseBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("date >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND date < '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", date, plus);
            /*string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
            */

            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }
            label3.Text = sum.ToString();


            int overall = int.Parse(label2.Text) - int.Parse(label3.Text);
            label5.Text = "Overall profit for date " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") +" =      Rs." + overall.ToString() ;


            /*string namequery = "SELECT itemName from ItemRecord where date = '" + date +"'";
            string itemname;
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(namequery, con))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", 5);
                con.Open();
                itemname = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
            */

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();

        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Filtering code can you share how you bind data to grid?

Comment: This is the total code that i used. I can share the complete code of the form.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling DB again why don't you select only those records which satisfy your date check. Have a look at the modified select command.

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord Where date >='"+dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND date < '"+date+"'" , con);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
adapter.Fill(yourDataSource);
```

Hope it helps.
If you want something else, write it down.

Comment: Have you set the DataSource of DataGridView after executing this command? If not then set it. It will set new data to the gridview.

Comment: i jusr replaced the line `adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord", con);` to `adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord Where date >='"+dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND date < '"+date+"'" , con);`

Comment: Write this in the end `dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];`

Comment: showing error :: it says "**Cannot find table 0.**"

Comment: Kindly watch whether the dataset has any rows/table in it or not after executing the query. If not then try to execute it within sqlserver to verify your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134352/discussion-between-fkr-and-m-adeel-khalid).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it necessary to filter the data as your code shows. Instead of filtering/selecting from the original data base, you can simply apply a row filter to the current `DataTable` like below. Assuming you want to filter the data to show all the dates between two dates. Using two text boxes, the user types in the first starting date in one text box then the ending second date in the second text box. The user clicks a “Filter” button to filter the `DataTable` to only show the dates between those two dates. If the user clears the textboxes and clicks the filter button, then the original unfiltered data will be displayed. Hope this helps.

```
DataTable dt;
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dt = GetYourDataTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void buttonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (tbDate1.Text == "" || tbDate2.Text == "") {
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";
  }
  else {
    DateTime sDate;
    DateTime eDate;
    if ((DateTime.TryParse(tbDate1.Text, out sDate)) && (DateTime.TryParse(tbDate2.Text, out eDate))) {
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Date >= #" + sDate + "# AND Date <= #" + eDate + "#");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Button1_Click` add this line after `adapter.Fill(dataset);` line

```
adapter.Fill(dataset, "ItemRecord");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["ItemRecord"];
```

Comment: it says "Cannot find table 0."

Comment: write tablename instead index

Comment: problem is when you click button1 you retrieve data from DB but you didn't bind it to gridview

Comment: How can I bind data in my case?